# Exponentiation complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, analysis

Based on this code:

```
int poow(int x,int y)
{
    if(y==0)
        return 1;

    if(y%2!= 0)
        return poow(x,y-1)*x;

    return poow(x,y/2)*poow(x,y/2); //this line 

}
```

I tried to see the complexity: We suppose that we have n=2^k

we have T(0)=1

T(n)=2*T(n/2)+C

T(n)=2^i * T(n/2^i)+i*c

for i=k we have T(n)=2^k * T(n/2^k) + k * c

T(n)=2^k * T(1) + k*c

T(n)=2^k * c2 + k * c

I am stuck here ? How can I continue the computation of complexity and what is the difference when changing this line:

```
return poow(x,y/2)*poow(x,y/2); //this line
```

with

```
int p=poow(x,y/2);
return p*p;
```

in term of complexity !

Comment: So.. what's your question in regards to code that you are having an issue with?

Comment: You've made a mistake. `T(n)=2*T(n/2)+C = T(n)=2*(2*T(n/4) + C)+C = 4*T(n/4) + 3C != 4*T(n/4) + 2C`

Comment: Not that important actually this mistake but thanks anyway.

Comment: The complexity of the second form is expressed by `T(n) = T(n/2) + C`. A common theme in CS where memory can be used to pre-pay for time.

Comment: Why not I have a recursive function with two subroutines so why not T(n)=2*T(n/2)+C.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The second form only calls itself recursively once.

Comment: the first code I have two two recursive calls and the second only one. which one is slower ? Obviously is the first one but I wanted to prove it.

Comment: The first is `O(n)`, the second is `O(lg n)`. I think it's pretty straight forward which is better :)

Comment: Yes I come up to the demonstration finally. thanks :) !

Comment: Last question is `return x*pow(x,n-1)` faster than the first code ? just to order them ? IMHO it is faster @StoryTeller

Comment: It's `O(n)` as well. They are asymptotically equivalent. Although the form that halves the exponent has a better coefficient on the asymptotically significant term, I think...

Comment: `x*pow(x,n-1)` could be *faster* than `pow(x,n-1)*x` (but probably isn't), but complexity isn't about speed, it's about how something *scales*. The two have the same complexity.

Comment: Sorry I meant the approach where the recursive function has only x*pow(x,n-1) so we have 3 codes.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that all these assumptions only hold when taking a mupliplication as being performed in O(1), while in general it is > O(n log n) (depending on the algorithm used). On a common cpu when restricted to native integer types this might not play a role, but when operating with arbitrarily big values it is a relevant factor.

Answer (score 1):

Start off with a proper recurrence. The complexity is solely based on `y`, so we can write the recurrence as

```
T(0) = 1

T(y) = y is even:     2 * T(y / 2)
       y is odd:      T(y - 1) + 1
```

Worst-case would be that every division by 2 leaves us with a odd number, which would lead to the complexity of

```
T(2^n-1) = 1 + 2 * (1 + 2 * (1 + 2 * ( ... * T(1)))) =
         = 2 ^ 0 + 2 ^ 1 + 2 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 3 + ... + 2 ^ (n - 1) + 2 ^ (n - 1) = 
         = 2 ^ n - 1 + 2 ^(n - 1) = 3 * 2 ^ (n - 1) - 1

T(y) = O(y)
```

Best-case would be a power of 2:

```
T(2^n) = 2 * 2 * ... * 2 * T(1) = 2 ^ n * (1 + 1) = 2 ^ (n + 1) = 2 * 2 ^ n

T(y) = O(y)
```

Now what if we optimized the whole function?

```
T'(0) = 1

T'(y) = y is even:   T(y / 2) + 1
        y is odd:    T(y - 1) + 1
```

Worst case:

```
T'(2^n - 1) = T(2^n - 2) + 1 = T(2^(n - 1) - 1) + 1 + 1 = ... =
            = T(1) + 1 + 1 + 1 + ... =
            = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ... =
            = 1 + ln(2^n) / ln(2) * 2 = 
            = 1 + 2 * n

T'(y) = O(log y)
```

Best case:

```
T'(2 ^ n) = T(1) + 1 + 1 + ... =
          = 2 + 1 + 1 + ... =
          = 2 + ln(2^n) / ln(2)
          = n + 2

T'(y) = O(log y)
```

So the optimized version is definitely faster (linear vs logarithmic complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Sometime code analysis focuses on the theory and not the actual.

Code has a bug.

```
if(y%2!= 0)
    return poow(x,y-1)*x;
// should be
if(y%2!= 0)
    return poow(x,y-y%2)*x;

// better alternative, use 
unsigned poow(unsigned x, unsigned y)
```

Without the fix, calling `poow(1,-1)` causes infinite recursion and likely stack-overflow. So O(∞) regardless in the last line is `return poow(x,y/2)*poow(x,y/2);` or `int p=poow(x,y/2);
return p*p;`.